# Rails destroy callbacks for child records not firing on parent update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm seeing an issue where destroy callbacks on a child record are not being fired when deleting the child record of a parent model. This issue emerged when updating records from a form, though I don't think that's relevant.

```
class Job
  has_many :assignments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :scheduled_assignments, -> { scheduled }, class_name: 'Assignment'

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :scheduled_assignments, dependent_destroy: true
end


class Assignment
  belongs_to :job

  after_destroy :call_me
  after_save :call_me

  def call_me
    puts "I got called"
  end
end

job = Job.create
job.update({ scheduled_assignment_ids: [1] })
  # a scheduled assignment is created, and the after_save 
  # callback is called in assignment

job.update({ scheduled_assignment_ids: [] })
   # the scheduled assignment is deleted, 
   # but the after_destroy callback is not fired
```

Because the Rails doc mention the child record should be deleted with a 'destroy' action, not 'delete', I'd expect callbacks to be fired on the `Assignment` object being deleted.

Comment: Can update trigger a destroy like this? Either you should be calling `job.destroy()`, or I'm missing something about how ActiveRecord works.

Comment: My thought that it should, especially as update triggers the save/create callbacks. Seems like a commit action should either trigger all callbacks or none of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using `after_remove`. After searching the [Rails source regarding collection associations](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb#L549):

```
def remove_records(existing_records, records, method)
  records.each { |record| callback(:before_remove, record) }

  delete_records(existing_records, method) if existing_records.any?
  records.each { |record| target.delete(record) }

  records.each { |record| callback(:after_remove, record) }
end
```

You can see that the `before_remove` and `after_remove` callbacks are called anytime child record is deleted, regardless of `delete` or `destroy`.

So, when adding an `after_remove` callback to my parent class, I can manually trigger a method on each child record deleted. Which is what I was after.

```
class Job
  has_many :assignments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :scheduled_assignments, -> { scheduled }, 
                                    class_name: 'Assignment', 
                                    after_remove: :teardown_assignment

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :scheduled_assignments, dependent_destroy: true

  def teardown_assignment(assignment)
    # callback here
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`after_destroy` is not in the list of callbacks triggered by `update`:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html (Section 3.2)

The docs make it look like this would work:

`after_destroy :call_me, on: [ :update ]`

Comment: `after_destroy :call_me, on: [ :update ]` did not work, there aren't any callbacks at all being fired in the child record.